# Is it possible to read ASCII control characters in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, browser, ascii

I am newly on XML and I need to know,

Is it possible to read ASCII control characters in XML? or

Is it possible to replace ASCII control characters in XML?

Comment: I've answered you as best I can, but it would be helpful if you'd give more details of what you're trying to achievve.

Comment: See 
Wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng: How does that help? It doesn't talk about control characters at all

Comment: It specifies how to add the hex value of characters to xml.  You would add the control characters by their hex value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML 1.1 allows for all Unicode characters other than U+0000, but XML 1.0 has a restricted character set. From [section 2.2 of the 5th edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets):

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

That's the underlying character set - you can't use CharRef etc to create them.

Unfortunately, XML 1.0 is basically what's in use everywhere; XML 1.1 never really took off. That means you shouldn't try to produce XML documents containing the ASCII control characters - they won't be valid XML documents, although lots of XML APIs will unfortunately let you create them anyway :(

Basically, you should remove the control characters before you pass your data to whichever XML API you're using. If you need to preserve them, you'll need to either create your own escaping, or something similar (e.g. UTF-8-encode the whole text, then represent that in base64... all quite nasty).

Comment: Hi Jon, your answer is useful. I have a XML file on my system but which also contains ASCII control characters. And I need to display that XML file on browser using C#. but I had getting errors. So is there any way to replace the ASCII control characters or skip that characters?

Comment: @SRJ: It's not a valid XML file, basically. You could load the file as a string (e.g. `File.ReadAllText`) if you know the encoding, replace the characters and then either parse it in memory or save it back to disk. You should investigate where the XML file came from though, and report the problem.

Comment: "XML 1.1 allows for all Unicode characters" isn't strictly true, U+0000 is considered a Unicode character, but isn't allowed in XML 1.1. All the rest are indeed allowed (and for that matter, the non-characters in the astral planes are allowed in both though they aren't allowed in Unicode though since they aren't allowed in a valid text file that can be considered an oversimplification or a bug in the spec depending on how one chooses to view that weirdness).

Comment: @JonHanna: Thanks, will edit for the U+0000. I haven't included the non-character aspect, as that's probably a bit beyond the OP's scope :)

Comment: I simply used as, string sMyXMLContent = "<your xml string>";
var validXmlChars = sMyXMLContent.Where(ch => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)).ToArray();

Comment: @SRJ: Well yes. The alternative is to work out your own escaping system, as I indicate in the answer. It's unfortunate, I know :(

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you for your useful answer.